# Efficiently Verifying Policy Changes on All Computers?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

In a convoluted AD structure with multiple OUs blocking inheritance, is there an *efficient* way to ensure a certain setting has actually propagated (i.e. audit policies; some registry key; etc.) to all machines?

At this point we review each computer's setting via gpresult and combine them into one large report.  There has to be a better way.

Comment: If you find "multiple OUs blocking inheritance" in a customer environment you may want to perform an in-depth survey. Blocking inheritance (multiple times) make me think of poor OU design, or general lack of Group Policy understanding -- LSDOU, Security filtering and WMI Filters can eliminate the most "needs" for blocking inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reviewing individual assets is a tedious way to go about this. Review your OU structure with `Get-GPInheritance` and look for those where `GpoInheritanceBlocked` is set. Those are the areas you need to focus on. If the block is no longer needed for any GPO, consider removing it. If it is needed for some but not all GPO's re-link the important GPO's that should not be blocked to those OU's so that they are still applied. This PowerShell will give you a list of OU's where inheritance has been blocked.

```
#require module ActiveDirectory
get-adObject -ldapfilter "(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)" | foreach {
    get-GPInheritance $_.distinguishedName | where { $_.GpoInheritanceBlocked -eq $true} | foreach {
        $_.Path
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP didn't state that he wants or needs to change inheritance blocking. To advise him to do so is an assumption that he wants to do so, which isn't the right approach. He wants to find out which GPO's are being applied, he doesn't necessarily want or need to change that. Audit, report, and evaluate. Then make changes if needed.

Comment: He did ask for a way `to ensure a certain setting has actually propagated `. Removing the block is one option. If that option is not viable I also wrote `re-link the important GPO's that should not be blocked `

Comment: Making sure a setting is being applied doesn't lead to "Remove inheritance blocking" as the first step. First find out if the setting is being applied. If it isn't being applied then figure out why. If it isn't being applied and you want it to be applied then make the appropriate change. Inheritance blocking is just one reason why a GPO may not be applied. Again; Audit, report, and evaluate. Then make the appropriate changes. I'm certainly not trying bust your chops, I'm only saying that you need to know what the source of the blocking is before you can prescribe a solution.

Comment: To be more succinct; removing inheritance blocking may allow a desired GPO setting to be applied but may then allow undesired GPO settings to be applied. Evaluate first, then plan and implement the appropriate change.

Comment: Yes, I agree there can be other causes. Was just trying to share some steps that would help in bringing some order to what the OP himself called a "convoluted AD structure"

Comment: Right. Hopefully you didn't take offense to my comments. Your answer was a terrific contribution to the question.

Comment: We're good. I re-worded my answer to be a little softer and things to consider before taking the remove step.

Answer (score 1):

GPO's don't propagate. If you want to know if a GPO is being applied to a particular computer or user then run gpresult or run the Group Policy Results wizard, targeting the specific computer or user.

Comment: Thanks @joeqwerty ! I've rephrased the question to clarify.  I'm trying to avoid running gpresult for each computer in the environment, but rather get one 'report' showing all settings for a certain computer.  For example, if we change a registry setting via a GPO, I'd like to know what computers in the environment do and don't have had that setting changed.

Comment: @David_Springfield In that case, the answer is "no" -- neither AD nor GP maintain a stateful information of clients. You may be able to leverage other tools (including roll-your-own) to perform point-in-time reporting.